# Use anchors/hashbangs in the URL to trigger functions on load?

Tags: javascript

Say someone is linked to the url, `example.com/#boom`

Can the hashbang in the url, `#boom` be linked to triggering a function like `boom()` on the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly? Boom function... ?

Comment: boom = any client-side function.

Comment: Hmm, JQuery may do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
  if(typeof window[hash] == "function")
    window[hash]();
};
```

If the function specified in the hash exists, then it will be called on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand what you really want... On your web page, you can add code that runs at page load, that examines the URL and that calls a suitable function accordingly. You will want to use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location) for this.

Comment: Look at Digital Plane's code, it's the kind of stuff I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with JavaScript:

```
if( window.location.hash ){
    var currentHash = window.location.hash;
    alert( "Yup! " + currentHash + " is set." );
}else{
    alert( "Nope!" );   
}
```

Now this is an example. Obviously you would want to call your call back function instead of outputting `currentHash`.

For more information on calling the function: http://w3future.com/html/stories/callbacks.xml

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ // Page onload
    if(location.hash == "#boom"){ // Hash is "boom"
        boom(); // call function boom()
    }
}
```