# Start FancyBox on page load without clicking

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript

I want to display a modal window using fancybox at webpage load. This window will display a web page that will allow to choose the desired language. The page displayed in the popup window will be a web page (`index_popup.php`) located in the same folder as the home page (`index.php`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch jQuery Fancybox on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load)

Answer (score 11):

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open('#popup_box');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution it is working when you want to open on load without click

Answer (score 4):

For fancybox 2: the documentation offers the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/, to which I've added a document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.fancybox.open([
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
            title : '1st title'
        },
        {
            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
            title : '2nd title'
        }    
    ], {
        padding : 0   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Fancybox popup once time for session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431862/fancybox-popup-once-time-for-session)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {

    function openFancybox() {
        // launches fancybox after half second when called
        setTimeout(function () {
                $.fancybox.open(
                    [
                        {
                            href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
                        }    
                    ]
                );
        }, 1500);
    };

    var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // create the cookie
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false; // second page load, cookie is active so do nothing
    } else {
        openFancybox(); // first page load, launch fancybox
    };
    // assign cookie's value and expiration time
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 1 // the number of days the cookie will be effective
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: How to make this banner clickable? I want to add a link behind then when the user clicks on this banner he should redirect to the link!

Comment: Take a look at the api http://fancybox.net/api ... you maybe able to use "content" with html code instead of "href"

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popup_box').fancybox().trigger('click'); 
});
```

[source](http://codepotato.co.uk/2010/10/opening-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load/)

Comment: Thanks pariss.. It works for me inside a function call.

Comment: it works outside of (document).ready.  example: function myfunction(){  $('#popup_box').fancybox().trigger('click'); }

Answer (score 1):

Although FancyBox doesn't support a way to auto launch, there have been a few workarounds that seem pretty successful. One notable method I've used is in the link below to a similar question. This should accomplish the onPageLoad:

[How to launch jQuery Fancybox on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <head>   
<script type="text/javascript">

    function autoClick() { 
    document.getElementById('onload').click();
    } 

    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="autoClick();">

<a class="fancybox-media" id="onload" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWydLB0nFew"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the first solution:

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open('#popup_box');
});
```

But I wasn't able to get it to load correctly, so I added a variable, then passed that in. It works exactly as I needed it to. Has the slider now, instead of loading each image separately.

This was my change:

```
window.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var box = $('#popup_box');
    $.fancybox.open(box);
});
```

Comment: This doen't add any value to the question.If you think previously provided answer has a problem, you are always welcome to comment or flag it.
If you think you had to modify a statement of previously given answer then try giving explanation around it why it solved the problem