# Fancybox popup once time for session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup, fancybox

I have a popup with fancybox that appear at load page.

I need to show the popup once a time, if the user change page and back on the page with popup doesn't reveal a second time.

I've read that could be use a cookie plug in (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) but i dont understant how integrate in this code...

I have a simple site in html/css.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function openFancybox() {
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#yt').trigger('click');
}, 500);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
var visited = $.cookie('visited');
if (visited == 'yes') {
    return false; // second page load, cookie active
} else {
    openFancybox(); // first page load, launch fancybox
}
$.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
    expires: 7 // the number of days cookie  will be effective
});
$("#yt").click(function() {
            $.fancybox({
                    'padding'        : 0,
                    'autoScale'      : false,
                    'transitionIn'   : 'none',
                    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
                    'title'          : this.title,
                    'width'          : 680,
                    'height'         : 495,
                    'href'           : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"),  'v/'),
                    'type'           : 'swf',
                    'swf'            : {
                        'wmode'              : 'transparent',
                        'allowfullscreen'    : 'true'
                    }
                });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body onload='$("#yt").trigger("click");'>

  <a id="yt" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROTYmNckBCw&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1"><img  src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For browser consistency, you may need to delay the fancybox load execution for the first time so try this code :

```
function openFancybox() {
    // launches fancybox after half second when called
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#yt').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // create the cookie
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false; // second page load, cookie is active so do nothing
    } else {
        openFancybox(); // first page load, launch fancybox
    };
    // assign cookie's value and expiration time
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 7 // the number of days the cookie will be effective
    });
    // your normal fancybox script
    $("#yt").click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            // your fancybox API options
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

See code at this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aVE9N/)**

**NOTES** :

- In order to see the cookie working, you may need to use jsfiddle's full screen mode http://jsfiddle.net/aVE9N/show/
- I would advice you to update (at least) your fancybox version from v1.3.1 to v1.3.4
- It's assumed you are loading properly the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) in your page

Comment: Is enough the file  jquery.cookie.js? i've added only this.
Also i have integrate your script but i dont think that run, sure i have wrong something...i have edited in the first post.

Comment: @user3519727 : does the jsfiddle work for you?, if so then you really need to debug what you might be doing wrong. And yes the jquery.cookie.js would be enough (apart from jQuery and fancybox of course)

Comment: @user3519727 : BTW, don't leave spaces inside the `href` as in your code above `...watch?  v=ROT...`

Comment: I've tried and is ok with the img.

if i wont put a video?

and for how many times is active the cookie? if i wont show another time the video? maybe after a 10minutes...is possible?  thanx so much

Comment: if i try to put a video from youtube appear a message in the lightbox: The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.

Comment: i've tried with this url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROTYmNckBCw&amp;fs=1&amp;autoplay=1

Comment: Resolved, i edited the first post with the correct code.
Thanks so much JFK!!

Comment: You know how close the popup when the video is finished?

Comment: @user3519727 : for youtube autoclose, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863405/1055987 ... it was written for fancybox v2.x so you may need to tweak the code to use the right API and callback options for fancybox v1.3.x

Comment: You know if is possible integrate this vimeo's video in the same script?   https://vimeo.com/67198403

Comment: with the vimeo's link doesnt run :(

Comment: @user3519727 : first I would advice you to update to v1.3.4 (again) and check this page for vimeo samples http://fancybox.net/vimeo

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery cookie plugin you suggested:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(typeof $.cookie('popupVideoPlayed') == 'undefined') {
        $.cookie('popupVideoPlayed', 'true'); // set a session cookie so it won't play again
        $('#yt').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Remember to delete the inline body onload event handler.

Comment: Sorry i'm not able with jquery. I've edited with your code and with the link to cookie.js but doesn't run, how i must delete the inline body onload???

Comment: Make the body tag look just like <body>, and put the code after the click event handler.

Comment: i have edited. But with this situation the popup never start.

Comment: Most likely the cookie has already been set. Open your browser developer tools (usually F12) and delete it, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

¡UPDATED!

If you're using the newest [JavaScript Cookie plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) this is for you:

**HTML**

```
<a class="c-p" href="#cookies" style="display: none;">Inline</a>
<div id="cookies" style="display: none;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos rem nulla quae dolorum omnis possimus, ducimus nisi pariatur harum debitis quo, excepturi nam ratione modi. Architecto, enim. Amet, saepe mollitia?</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout( function() {jQuery('.c-p').trigger('click'); },1500);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (Cookies.get('visited')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Cookies.set('visited', 'no', { expires: 7 });
    } 
    if (Cookies.get('visited') == 'yes') {
        return false;
    } else {
        openFancybox();
        Cookies.set('visited', 'yes');
    }
    jQuery('.c-p').fancybox();
});
```

Note: I implemeted it in my custom WordPress theme and it worked perfectly.