# Using fancybox w/ jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox

I have fancybox loading on page load on http://cobosboutique.com. I want to add a cookie that only lets it load every 7 days. I found this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431862/fancybox-popup-once-time-for-session#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431862/fancybox-popup-once-time-for-session#_=_) but when I use it I get an error that says the Content cannot be loaded. I tried commenting on that thread but I don't have enough points to do that. Does anyone have any ideas what is causing this? I've removed the code for the cookie for now. But this is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="../template/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../template/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../template/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openFancybox() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#yt').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        return false; // second page load, cookie active
    } else {
        openFancybox(); // first page load, launch fancybox
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes', {
        expires: 0 // the number of days cookie  will be effective
    });
    $("#yt").click(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            href: this.href,
            type: "inline"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<a class="fancybox" href="#yt">test</a>
    <div id="yt" style="display:none; text-align: center;"><h2>VIP TEXT CLUB!</h2>
<h3>Get exclusive access to sales and new arrivals!</h3>
<h3>Text "COBO" to 51660 and receive 10% off your entire purchase! </h3>
<h3>10% offer only applies to first time text club subscribers.</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that `#yt` is the ID of your **target** content (your hidden `div` that supposed to be in fancybox) therefore you cannot *bind* and *trigger* a `click` event to that selector but the one with *class* `fancybox` (the **trigger** element), which is actually pointing to the `#yt` selector :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#yt">test</a>
```

So, in your `openFancybox()` function you need to replace this line

```
$('#yt').trigger('click');
```

... by this one

```
$('.fancybox').trigger('click');
```

Then *bind* the `click` event to `.fancybox` replacing this line

```
$("#yt").click(function () {
```

... by this one

```
$(".fancybox").click(function () {
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3mo26zov/)**