# Launch FancyBox on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, onload

I am using [fancyapps.com](http://www.fancyapps.com/)'s FancyBox and I was wondering how to call a fancybox.ajax when the page loads.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#what").fancybox();
});

<a href="what.html" id="what" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax"></a>
```

Comment: It's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the method on document ready

HTML

```
<a id="myFancybox" href="http://mydomain.com/mine.jpg" />
```

and script is

```
$(function(){

    $("#myFancybox").fancybox();

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

`document.ready` specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Ok but what is the method to call file.txt via ajax?

Comment: @4WebDev: Give your remote file name as the value of href proprty. Fancy box will bring the content of that file in the fancybox

Comment: Yeah I just tried it and no luck... Here is what I have
<a href="what.html" id="what" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax"></a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#what").fancybox();
   });

Comment: @4WebDev: Probably you have some other script errors in the page, check for the console tab of firebug to see what are those