# Loading Fancybox only when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, fancybox

I'm a designer in Fort Lauderdale, and I'm using fancybox.js in one of my projects. I have a main landing page where there is a huge chart of names, and when you click on the name, the fancybox pops up with more information, photos, etc. However, when I load this main page, it tries to load all of the content for the entire site, and it takes forever. Is there a way that I can set the fancybox.js to only load when the fancybox is clicked/visible?

I've read this tutorial about how to launch Fancybox on page load, and I basically want to do the opposite. I only want the fancybox to load when clicked so the main landing page runs faster. [How to launch jQuery Fancybox on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807271/how-to-launch-jquery-fancybox-on-page-load/3728591#3728591)

I'd appreciate any help you could give. Thanks!

Comment: do you have an example? any code?

Comment: This is a very early version of the project: http://interactive.sun-sentinel.com/signingday2/ so you can see the fancybox popups and how they have videos, photos, etc. I want the Fancybox to load only when visible/clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just do in your html :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{target}">the link I want to open on click only</a>
```

.. and then use this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options
  });
});
```

Check the documentation for the API options you may need or want to add : For fancybox v1.3.4 http://fancybox.net and for fancybox v2.x http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Could I possibly use "onComplete" to load the ad tag (which is javascript) after the fancybox has been loaded?

Comment: `onComplete` is a v1.3.4 option, make sure you are using that version.... and yes, you can use `onComplete` inside fancybox (where it says API options) with this format `"onComplete": function(){// your javascript here}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. In the code provided above, what would I put for "the link I want to open on click only"? Each fancybox is called up using <div id="inline1"> and so forth corresponding to the #inline1 in the chart.

Comment: This is a very early version of the project: http://interactive.sun-sentinel.com/signingday2/ so you can see the fancybox popups and how they have videos, photos, etc. I want the Fancybox to load only when visible/clicked.